# Send JSON Array with key

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio

```
  my output "abc":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":1,"4":2,"5":1,"6":2,"7":1,"8":2,"9":1,"10":2,"11":1}]
   
//mycode 

   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        for(QuizAttempt order_product:products){
            //jsonArray.put(order_product.getAns());
            jsonObject.put(order_product.getId(),order_product.getAns());
        }
        //jsonObject.put()
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        paramObject.put("abc",jsonArray);
```

I getting out as I have shown above and above is my code but I want my output as

```
 "abc":[{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"1","4":"2","5":"1","6":"2","7":"1","8":"2","9":"1","10":"2","11":"1"}]
```

Help me to solve this problem
Thank you all in advance

Comment: `jsonObject.put(order_product.getId(),""+order_product.getAns());` OR change datatype of `getAns()` to in String in your pojo file

Comment: and one more thing is there any other option to send value with key in json array ???

Comment: @DeepParsania I have one more query please see my output it is sending object within array I don't have to send object I have to send like this   "abc":["1":"1","2":"2","3":"1","4":"2","5":"1","6":"2","7":"1","8":"2","9":"1","10":"2","11":"1"] how can I do this

Comment: you can use HashMap instead of jsonObject [Here tutorial for it](https://abhiandroid.com/java/hashmap)

Comment: @DeepParsania it gives me this "abc":["{44=2, 45=1, 42=1, 43=2}"]} but I want "abc":["44":"2","45":"1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change in object**

```
 jsonObject.put(order_product.getId(),""+order_product.getAns());
```

**Change in Datatype**

```
change the datatype of getAns() to in String in your POJO file
```

Comment: Thank you for solution  . and I have posted one more query in above post's comment please answer that .